# How do I export a list (of data) from a python file into a separate external file?

Tags: python, list, file, pickle

I have a python file that runs a machine learning algorithm that identifies circles in an image. From this python file, I am able to get all the coordinates (x and y) of every bounding box placed around the circles. I am appending all the coordinates into a local variable `xlist`/`ylist` (a list of all the integer values of the coordinates).

What is the best way to save an external file (either a `.txt` or  `.py`) of `xlist` and `ylist`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pickle library. It saves the data as its original data type only.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in a `.txt` file.

**Try this**

```
file = open('xlistFile.txt', 'w')

for item in xlist:
    file.write(str(item))

file.close()
```

You can do the same for ylist

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to pickle like:

```
with open("xlist.pkl", "wb") as fw:
    pickle.dump(xlist, fw)
```